# Android OpenGL Thread

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am making an android game and I need help. How can I send **gl** and **this.context** to the thread?

This is the code:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Building b=new Building();
                b=new Building();
                b.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);
                first=0;
                bulid++;
                bubbles.add(b); 
            }
        }).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify your question a bit more? Where do you get `gl` from?

As OpenGL E.S. (As well as OpenGL itself) is a stateful graphics library, you should not use `gl` in another thread other than the rendering thread.

When you create a GLSurface, a new thread is being created. The existing one will continue to exist (and i.e. handle `onTouchEvent()` calls).

Using `gl` in any other thread than the rendering thread may mess up the state-machine and your GL-calls will not be processed, since the new thread doesn't use the same OpenGL context.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an inner class such that:

```
public class ClassName implements Runnable{

    GL10 mGl;
    Context mContext;

    public ClassName(GL10 mGl, Context mContext){
        this.mGl = mGl;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public void run() {
        Building b=new Building();
        b=new Building();
        b.loadGLTexture(mGl, mContext);
        first=0;
        bulid++;
        bubbles.add(b); 
    }

}
```

and use this Runnable implementation in your code:

```
new Thread(new ClassName(gl, this.context)).start();
```